# Linq to Sql - Partial Insert/Update Queries for *All* Tables

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a database with twenty-something tables in it. All of them have four columns used for auditing: CreateDate, CreatedBy, UpdateDate, and UpdatedBy.

At the moment, we are using partials for each table's Insert and Update methods, and executing a dynamic query, like so:

```
    partial void InsertStuff(Stuff instance)
    {
        instance.CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        instance.CreatedBy = "web app";

        this.ExecuteDynamicInsert(instance);
    }
```

That does the job; the problem is that we have to create a partial method for every table, manually. **Is there any way to partial/override *all* insert and update operations in a given context?** It would add a nice bit of brevity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scoured the interwebs looking for a way to do this, never found one (at least, without doing some crazy code generation that's not worth the effort). I'm likely switching to Entity Framework in future projects, so I'll just mark this as the answer.

Unless someone else comes up with something, of course.